# Google Cast Widevine PSSH

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, mpeg-dash, widevine

I'm using official custom receiver from [Github](https://github.com/googlecast/CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM) and I'm trying to play MPEG-DASH Widevine protected video stream. Receiver is running on Nexus Player 5.1.1. I'm correctly setting customData and licence server url. The problem is that player (DRM component) is not correctly generating needed data for POST request to the licence server. This data should be generated with data from [PSSH box](http://docs.unified-streaming.com/documentation/protect/widevine.html) and include information about DRM client and more. Below is the almost empty POST request (omitted some CORS specific headers) with request body containing only two bytes (08 04)

```
POST XYZ HTTP/1.1
Host: XYZ
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2
Origin: ABC
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus Player Build/LMY47V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.75 Safari/537.36 CrKey/1.13.31432
content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://ABC/ftp-custom/CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM/mpl.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB
CAST-DEVICE-CAPABILITIES: {"display_supported":true}
..
```

The correct request body (on Windows / Chrome) should look like this (ommited "non-human readable" content within request body)

```
POST XYZ HTTP/1.1
Host: XYZ
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1763
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36
Origin: http://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com
Accept: */*
Referer: http://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: cs,en;q=0.8
ChromeCDM-Windows-x86
architecture_name x86-32
company_name Google
model_name ChromeCDM
platform_name Windows2
```

Thank you for any how to make this working correctly.

Comment: The project on github that you referenced is really not an official receiver, it is just a sample; I suggest you use https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample which is a reference receiver and try to reproduce your issue there and then report.

Comment: @AliNaddaf - I tried it and same issue with it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you got sample media? You can either put the pssh data in the init segment of the mp4 or in the mpd